# How to import external python files not using Google Drive

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I started recently with Google Colab for working on Kaggle Airbus competition. I have previously written my code on my computer and run it locally, but computing resoucres started to be not enough - I moved to Google Colab

I started from cloning my repo using `!git clone http://url/repo.git` which went ok, my data has been inserted in `/content/repo` folder. I followed instructions about copying data from kaggle to Google Colab directly without download&upload it.
The files' structure are:

```
/
- Content:
--- Airbus_project:
------ train.py
------ input:
----------- train_data (folder with images)
------ keras_frcnn:
----------- data_generators.py
----------- config.py
```

I also saw that running `!python3 train.py` is not working well if I want to make changes in my code (and `!git pull` does not work), so I copied code from file `train.py` inside one cell of notebook.

The cell starts of course from importing some modules

```py
from __future__ import division
import random
(...)
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from keras import backend as K
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.layers import Input
from keras.models import Model
from keras_frcnn import config, data_generators
(...)
```

And when I try to run it I get error `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_frcnn'`. I was looking for help about this question and most of the results are proposing to use Google Drive and add

```py
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive')
```

But I can't store my data on Google Drive due to not enough space (Kaggle data is about 35 GB).

Is there any way to convice Google Colab to look for those modules in `keras_frcnn` folder, which is in the same folder as `train.py` file?